# Rails Find all nested Albums or Collections in a Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here are my two models:

Collection:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :children, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Collection", foreign_key: "parent_id", optional: true
  has_many :albums, dependent: :nullify

end
```

Album:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :collection, optional: true
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

end
```

I need a way to find all Albums and/or Collections within a parent Collection.

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

This will allow me to access a list of all the photos within a parent Collection etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`access a list of all the photos within a parent Collection`

First approach, recursive call get_photos from the parent Collection to its children then its grand-children and so on ... until there's no more child Collection.

```rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ...
 def get_photos
   albums.map(&:photos).flatten.tap |photos|
     photos << children.map(&:get_photos).flatten
   end
 end
end
```

This might call many queries.

Second approach, migrating the Collection table to add the `collection path` column, so if the parent Collection `c1` id is 1, its path is `/1`, its children, for instances, `c2` (id: 2) and `c3`(id: 3) then c2 path is `/1/2` and c3 path is `/1/3`, and so on ... Each time you create a child Collection under a parent Collection, you set its path `#{parent_path}/#{id}`.

Now you could use the query `where('path LIKE ?', "#{parent_path}/%")` to get all children collections of the parent Collection.

```rb
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ...
 def get_photos
   collection_ids = where('path LIKE ?', "#{self.path}/%").pluck(&:id)
   album_ids = Album.where(collection_id: collection_ids).pluck(&:id)
   Photo.where(album_id: album_ids).all
 end
end
```

you could add directly the collection-path to the Photo table if you want to call only one query.

According to the book [SQL Anti-pattern](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns/), your problem is `Naive Trees` (Always Depend on One’s Parent).  The second approach is one solution for it - `Path Enumeration`, others are `Nested Sets` and `Closure Table`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.  I will definitely look into that solution.  MAny thanks!